# Upload large file to Sharepoint with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to upload a photo to a sharepoint library. If I use a relatively small file (370KB) then it works without any problems.
But if I try to upload a file that is about 3MB large then I get the error:
"Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: NotFound."
translated:
"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

I read that it should be possible to set the max message size, but I found no way to set such a thing in the ClientContext object.

This is the code I use:

```
    private void UploadFileCallback(object state)
    {
        var args = (List<object>)state;
        var itemContainer = (ISharepointItemContainer)args.ElementAt(0);
        var fileInfo = (FileInfo)args.ElementAt(1);

        var sharepointList = _context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(itemContainer.ListName);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile;
        FileCreationInformation newFile;

        using (FileStream fs = fileInfo.OpenRead())
        {
            byte[] content = new byte[fs.Length];

            newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
            int dummy = fs.Read(content, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            newFile.Content = content;
            newFile.Url = itemContainer.AbsoluteUrl + "/" + fileInfo.Name;
            uploadFile = sharepointList.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
            _context.Load(uploadFile);
        }

        _context.ExecuteQuery();

        if (FileUploadCompleted != null)
        {
            FileUploadCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am running into this as well and have been trying multiple work arounds with no real results.  Have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is to go to the **Web Applications Management** section in the **Central Administration** site for SharePoint.  Select the **General Settings** for the web app that you are deploying to and increase the maximum upload size.

The second thing to try is to add this to your **web.config**:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800"/>
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This will let you set the size to something larger.

Comment: Hello,
thanks for the answer. I will try it tomorrow and let You know if it worked...

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay, I verified the setting in central administration and it is set to 50 MB. But the error arises already with files of 3 MB! I tried also to add your xml to the web.config but without success. But is the Web.config used by Sharepoint? Because this silverlight application runs within a silverlight web part...

Answer (score 0):

By default, SharePoint has a 50MB max limit per upload. IIS 7 (not sure about other versions) has a 30 MB max limit per upload. You will need to add the XML configuration that Ryan provided to your SharePoint website's web.config, in IIS. This is your front-end web server.

Comment: This isn't a limit of sharepoint or iis per se, I believe it's a limit in the size of file being transferred through the web service call back in the client object model.

Comment: Mark; Please refer the following links for the default max upload limitation of SharePoint (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487972.aspx) and IIS 7 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968802(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The limit you're reaching is because the webservice that handles Client Object Model requests has a maximum message size. You can either increase that size, but another solution is to use WebDAV to upload the document, this will help if you don't have access to the server.

The .NET Client Object Model has a method [File.SaveBinraryDirect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee543346.aspx) for that, and that's probably your best bet.

If you were using the Silverlight Client Object Model that method is not available and you'll have write some additional code: see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599489.aspx#Y796), second part. The first part descibes how to increase the maximum message size.

This should increase your maximum upload size to the one set in Central Admin (typically 50MB), pointed out in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

The default upload size limit for the SharePoint client object model is 2 MB. You can change that limit by modifying the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` property of the service.

This can be done in two ways:

- programatically - as described in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599489.aspx#Y796) - tho this won't work in Silverlight for example
- trough the powershell. On the server where you have SharePoint installed, fire up the SharePoint Management Shell (make sure you run it under the farm administrator account) and run the following commands.

  $ws = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
  $ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 52428800

  $ws.Update()

This will change the upload limit to 52428800 bytes - or 50 MB. Now, restart the website hosting your SharePoint site (or the entire IIS) for the changes to take effect.